# Autowire a class that extends a collection in Spring

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-annotations

I've got a class that extends a collection, specifically a HashMap. I'd like to use it as an autowired field in another class, however when I try to use the @autowired or @resource annotations in the following way:

```
@Autowired
private myCollectionClass<String, Object> myCollectionClass;
```

I get the error: no qualifying bean of type [my collection class]

How can I autowire the class?

(I cannot use xml in the project)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use @Resource specifying the bean id

```
@Resource(name="myCollection")
private MyCollectionClass<String, Object> myCollectionClass;
```

Or you could use @Qualifier in conjunction with @Autowired

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("myCollection")
private MyCollectionClass<String, Object> myCollectionClass;
```

Comment: throws "No bean named 'myCollection' is defined"

Comment: Captain Obvious Says: So define a bean named "myCollection"

Answer (score 0):

have you annotated `myCollectionClass`?

If not, You need to annotate `myCollectionClass` as well with `@Component` for spring container to qualify the object based on class name or class type.

You can also use `@Qualifier` and specify the qualifier class name.

Comment: I had annotated the collection class as a component before autowiring it in another class, but its still the same error